# с какой стороны блока пришла мышь javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

Подскажите пожалуйста как на чистом javascript реализовать появление фона с определенной стороны при навелении мыши https://www.cartoonnetwork.ru/show/adventure-time/games

Answer (score 2):

```js
$(function () {
    $('div').mouseenter(function (e) {
        var jEl = $(this),
            w = jEl.outerWidth(),
            h = jEl.outerHeight(),
            off = jEl.offset(),
            x = e.pageX - off.left,
            y = e.pageY - off.top,
            xShift, // сдвиг от правой или левой границы
            yShift, // сдвиг от верхней или нижней границы
            xText,
            yText,
            itogText;

        if (x / w > .5) {
            xShift = w - x;
            xText = 'справа';
        } else {
            xShift = x;
            xText = 'слева';
        }

        if (y / h > .5) {
            yShift = h - y;
            yText = 'снизу';
        } else {
            yShift = y;
            yText = 'сверху';
        }

        itogText = (xShift < yShift) ? xText : yText;

        jEl.text(itogText);
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="width: 100px; height: 100px; padding: 20px; margin: 20px; background: red;"></div>
```

Вот пример с JQ как можно реализовать определение откуда мышь заходит в блок. Остаётся немного доработать под ваши нужны

Comment: А как будет на чистом javascript без jQuery?

Answer (score 2):

Вот пример на чистом javascript:

```js
var box = document.getElementById('box');

box.addEventListener("mouseover", function(e) {

  // Определяем центр
  var centerX = box.offsetLeft + box.offsetWidth / 2;
  var centerY = box.offsetTop + box.offsetHeight / 2;
  
  // Определяем позиции
  var textX = (e.clientX < centerX) ? 'Слева' : 'Справа';
  var textY = (e.clientY < centerY) ? 'Сверху' : 'Снизу';
 
  // Определяем сдвиг
  var shiftX = (e.clientX > centerX) ? e.clientX - centerX : (e.clientX - centerX) * -1;
  var shiftY = (e.clientY > centerY) ? e.clientY - centerY : (e.clientY - centerY) * -1;
  
  // Обновляем текст у блока в зависимости от сдвига
  box.innerText = (shiftX > shiftY) ? textX : textY;
});
```

```css
#box {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 10px;
  background: green;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 22px;
  line-height: 200px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="box"></div>
```